# Is T discrete topology on X or not?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I want to verify my argument  from  question of my assignments in topology.

> For each n$\in  \mathbb{N}$ , let $X_n =\mathbb{R}$ and let $T_n$ be discrete topology on $X_n$. Let T be product topology on X=$\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$ . Is T discrete topology on X or not?

I think It will be discrete topology as every element of  $P(\prod_{\mathbb{N}} X_n)$, where P(X) means power set of X are in X.

Am I right?

Comment: No. The product topology is the smallest topology that makes the projection functions continuous. Is the singleton set $\{(0,0,...)\}$ open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not the discrete topology. The set $\{(0, 0, 0, \dots,)\}$ is not open, as infinitely many of the pre-images under the projection maps are not the entire space.

To provide more detail: for $T$ to be the discrete topology, every subset of $X$ must be open. It will therefore suffice to show that a single subset of $X$ is not open. This set will be the singleton $A = \{(0, 0, \dots)\}$.

Let $\pi_n$ be the canonical projection function from $X_n$ to $X$. As $X$ has the product topology, a subset $V$ of $X$ is open iff every point of $V$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $\pi_n^{-1}(U) = X_n$ for all but finitely many $n$. However, $\pi_n^{-1}(A) = \{0\}$ for all $n$. Infinitely many preimages fail to be the entire space. The defining characteristic of open sets in $X$ has failed, and so, $A$ is not open. Thus, the topology of $T$ is different from the discrete topology.

Comment: @DuncanRamange Can you please  elaborate on why {(0,0,0,...,)} is not open?

Comment: For me your explanation was not sufficient so I am requesting you for a more detailed explanation

Comment: @No-One I have expanded on my answer. Please let me know if there are further details you would like me to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

The box topology would be the discrete topology; but the product topology is smaller.  One way to see it is that the product topology is the coarsest making the projections continuous.

However, *every* function from a discrete space is continuous.  That's it's the finest topology, period.

The product topology is in fact strictly coarser, because it doesn't include the entire power set.  It only includes *finite* products of non-empty open sets.